# SSL Cert Error Apache2

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, apache2

I'm getting a strange ssl error issue.

On my Ubuntu 18.04 only runs an apache2 server.
In the config i've linked all SSL Certs.

(SSLCertificateFile, SSLCertificateKeyFile and SSLCertificateChainFile).

These are also not self signed, i've got them from my hosting provider.

The weird part is, from https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ i've got an A+ on the config.

I've checked a lot of SSL-Checker online, and always got an A or A+, but three of them, couldnt even connect to my site.

And thats the issue, from some devices (like my Laptop/my phone) etc i can connect to my page. But on some other devices, it is not possible (some checker can connect, some others cant).

The Error their getting is on Chrome: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

And on Firefox: SSL_ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR_ALERT

But also only sometimes. If i spam the redirect button, for a short moment the page is loading, after that the error is comming back.

I've checked several pages online, and took any advice.
But it is not working, and i dont have a clear error.
I am pretty sure, its a config issue.
But i did it exactly like they did: https://www.ionos.com/community/markdown-migration/install-a-ionos-ssl-certificate-on-ubuntu-1604/

(addittionaly i added the intermediate cert, and like all the checkers (which could connect) tell, its all right).

(SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2 +TLSv1.3)

But why this error appears sometimes?

PS:

- Time is synced on the Server
- No Apache error.log (it exists, but nothing fails)
- Config Syntax is correct

I really dont know, what i am doing wrong, i would appreciate any help.
Thank you all

Comment: Basically you are saying that you did everything correct but it does not work. Only your problem is not reproducible just based on the information you've provided. Given that this problem is specific to your site even if everything seems to be properly configured you might need to share the actual (and exact) URLs you've used for testing so that others can try to reproduce your issue and dig deeper.

Comment: Well, yes i think i did everything correct, but it is only working sometimes, as i decribed it. Thats the thing, that confuses me.
Anyway, i dont want to share my domain, cause of the privacy things...but if u wanna have any further informations, send me the test/things u wanna know.

Comment: Can you show us you config file?